# How to make Solution Explorer return to its previous state after clearing search?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, projects-and-solutions

I currently have a VS installation with no extensions to see how that works out. For navigation that means making heavy use of `Ctrl+;` aka `Search Solution Explorer`. While the search itself is ok, it has one major drawback for me that makes it a pain to use for me (both with keyboard and mouse):

Solution with two projects, one collapsed, one opened:

[image]

Use `Ctrl+;` and start typing until match found from collapsed project

[image]

What I want now is to simply clear the search and return to the previous view. Seems like a pretty standard requirement, no? But there seems to be no such functionality built in. Problem with the current commands that come close (pressing `Esc`, clicking `Back` or `Home` buttons in Solution Explorer Toolbar) is all the same: they have the extremely annoying behaviour that they insist on suddenly uncollapsing the previously collapsed project and track the match found! (Btw the `Track Active Item in Solution Explorer` option is turned of in the options). This makes no sense from a UX point of view? You select some kind of 'undo' command, the search box clears which is expected, but then suddenly there's an item visible from a previous search:

[image]

So if the collapsed project has like 50 items in it, solution explorer is now useless visually since it litters the screen with stuff you don't want to see, and worse you have to manually collapse the project again to return to the previous view.

Is there a way around this? I thought maybe keyboard shortcuts for Back/Home would be different, but the commands do not seem to be registered. I looked into `EnvDTE80.DTE2.ToolWindows.SolutionExplorer` but it has no properties/methods that have anything to do with this issue. And somewhere in the tree there is a `Microsoft.VisualStudio.PlatformUI.SolutionPivotNavigator` which is probably the class responsible for this behaviour, but I have no idea how to access it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recently updated to VS2013 SP3 and I have the impression there was a change (or I didn't notice this properly earlier, though my question says otherwise): if I use the `Back` button in the Solution Explorer view it properly takes me back to the previous view without expanding anything that wasn't expanded before. Using `Esc` or clearing the search box still behave the same which is a pitty, but at least if I remember to use just the back button it's workable.

**update** Not really an answer but since I started using Edit.NavigateTo (which is basically 'Go to Anything' including symbols/files) bound to a keyboard shortcut I found no reason to use Window.SolutionExplorerSearch anymore.